# MS SQL database schema change without data loss

Tags: .net, sql-server, database

The task is to make changes to current tables structure without recreating these tables.

Is there a tool which resolves this task without making developers to write sql queries?

Thanks

Comment: SSMS can generate scripts by using the GUI to modify the tables, or is there some reason why this won't work for you?

Comment: I have two databases: one with updated structure and second with old structure. I need synchronize db structures. Data in the second database should not be chanded or lost. Thats why SSMS is not approach

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that tries to solve this problem.  Is this a one shot thing, or do you have a bunch of databases with the old structure (your customers maybe) and have to upgrade them all?  It's common to write scripts that update databases from one version to new schema, and sometimes it's hard.  I bet you'll have to make developers write sql queries, but post here if you find something.  Also look for forums around "Simple-talk.com" if anyone has a tool for this it's likely Redgate does and I think they're behind simple-talk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some kinds of changes can be made without loss and some can't.

Have a look at [RedGate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) - it will tell you when operations have possible loss consequences.